# When I try and do an update I get errors, reporting unsigned repository files. How do I fix this?

Tags: apt, updates

I am running 16.04.
I get the following error when trying to update :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-release-upgrader/ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk_16.04.18_all.deb
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

Plus two similar ones which I can't post as they are regarded as including links.

The output from apt-get update shows additional information, such as :

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository '[http:]//archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
```

Can you please help ?

Comment: Change the server and try again.

Comment: The website http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ reports that the two hyperlinks in your question are working.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar errors caused by trying to manually copy `/var/lib/apt/lists/` form one machine to another.

Try moving all contents from `/var/lib/apt/lists/` to `/tmp/listsbak/` then running `apt-get update`

```
mkdir /tmp/listsbak/ && sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/listsbak/ && sudo apt-get update
```

If the newly downloaded lists are throwing the same errors perhaps include in your question or a comment your machines `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any list files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: Got similar errors after the mv : For example "W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:9 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:9"

Comment: Got similar errors after the mv : For example "W: GPG error: [http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease] : At least one invalid signature was encountered." After copying sources.list and sources.list.distUpgrade to sources.list.d/ the errors for apt-get update were such as "W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:9 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:9". Did I do this right ? When you said "include" should I have done a move rather than a copy ?

Comment: I was not clear when I typed "include". I meant to communicate that you should include the contents in your question or a comment.  Now we need to remove the copied files.